# Launch terminal from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, terminal, unix

I recently switched to Eclipse (Helios) for my programming needs, and I like it very much.

There is just on thing that is driving me crazy, how can I launch (compile and run) my code into the native mac osx terminal.

I tried creating an "external tools configuration", but that just starts the terminal without outputting the application.

What I do now is right-click on the binary in the Project Explorer and then "Open With" and then "Other" and then I pick the terminal app from the list. But this solution is driving me nuts.

Please help.

Comment: With `External Tools` you can do pretty much everything you want. For example I've set up an external tool to compile my code and run the task remotely on UNIX.

Comment: Like i've written, that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

It's all about defining the *External Tool* correctly.

For example, the following should work if your selected file is a Unix executable.

1. Open a new External Tool configuration.
2. Set the location to `/usr/bin/open`
3. Set Working directory as `${selected_resource_loc}`
4. Set the arguments to `-a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ${selected_resource_loc}`

**When you run make sure you select "src"** [image]

This should work. You could improve it further. You could even write an AppleScript that would do that and run it using `osascript`.

Comment: The ${selected_resource_loc} doesn't work, I added the complete path name and that does work. Thank you.

Comment: @bing, Did you ever get the ${selected_resource_loc} to work?  I have the same issue. =(

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working with the Terminal.app, but it does work with iTerm2 (http://www.iterm2.com/, which is in general a better alternative to the Termianl.app). Also, I really like the embedded terminal option of Aptana.

Comment: use ${container_loc} instead of ${selected_resource_loc}