# Run and compile C program using ncurses.h in Mac Terminal from Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, terminal, ncurses

I'm using CDT 8.6.0 for Eclipse Luna with OS X Yosemite and instead of running my program in the Eclipse's console I want to do it in Mac Terminal app from Eclipse.

I've followed this instructions: [Launch terminal from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901118/launch-terminal-from-eclipse). With them I've managed to open my project directory in a new Terminal window, but it doesn't compile and run my program, which only has one source file (main.c).

I think I'm not using the correct arguments, ¿could you help me please?. I'm just beginning to work with Terminal and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing...

The program is so simple:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    printw("Hello World!");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the first time I work with ncurses library and when I compile and run the program directly form Terminal it works correctly, but when I do it in the Eclipse's console it seems to work but also displays a bunch of characters before the output that shouldn't be there...

I'll be glad to read your advices, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Eclipse terminal does not support ANSI escapes; this question was asked before in *[Support ANSI terminal color escape sequences in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111324/support-ansi-terminal-color-escape-sequences-in-xml)*, indicating that there is a plugin which may help (see *[Eclipse plugin – ANSI Escape in Console](http://mihai-nita.net/2013/06/03/eclipse-plugin-ansi-in-console/)*).

Comment: Thank you very much! The plugin works. I didn't even know that this strange characters were ANSI escapes, I've much to learn... I'm already struggling with the problem of launching the program in Terminal from Eclipse, any idea of that? Thanks again.